# install FirstResponderKit in Azure SQL DB?

Tags: azure-sql-database, sp-blitz, sp-blitzfirst

I've just downloaded the newest version (20190128) of FirstResponderKit from BrentOzar.com, and tried to install it on Azure SQL DB.
I'm getting these errors:

```
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_AllNightLog, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 13]
Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.procedures' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_AllNightLog_Setup, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 1492]
Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.procedures' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 2801]
Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.all_objects' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_BlitzLock, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 28063]
Reference to database and/or server name in 'msdb.dbo.sysjobs' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_DatabaseRestore, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 35912]
Reference to database and/or server name in 'master.sys.xp_dirtree' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.
```

It installs nicely on my SQL Server 2008.

Do FirstResponderKit work on Azure?

**Edit:**
Most of it runs, and I've started to change sp_blitz, so that it will run as well. please see [my github](https://github.com/HenrikStaunPoulsen/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) if you want to test it.

**Edit2:**
I've run it against a new Azure SQL database that I've moved from on-prem. It found two issues for me (caused by Microsoft Data Migration Assistant) about statistics not updated, and many indexes that were disabled. I think that other people will find similar issues, if we could get this version into the main release.  
 
Testers Needed!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit) - (highlighting mine)

**The First Responder Kit runs on:**

- SQL Server 2008, 2008R2, 2012, 2014, 2016, 2017 on Windows - yes,
  fully supported
- SQL Server 2017 on Linux - yes, fully supported except sp_AllNightLog
  and sp_DatabaseRestore, which require xp_cmdshell, which Microsoft
  doesn't provide on Linux
- SQL Server 2000, 2005 - not supported by Microsoft anymore, so we
  don't either
- Amazon RDS SQL Server - fully supported
- **Azure SQL DB - It's a dice roll. Microsoft changes DMV contents in here without warning, so no guarantees**

Comment: can you get it to work? has it ever been working?

Comment: I've tried to make a version of sp_blitz that works on Azure SQL DB. See https://github.com/HenrikStaunPoulsen/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/issue_1970/HenrikStaunPoulsen  Now, I'm looking for people that will test it.

Comment: I'm just running into this too. Is there any update in 2022?

Comment: Brent said in the videos he made this year that Azure is still a dice roll, Microsoft change things too often without warning for him to maintain it.
I get the feeling that he's saying that if you are serious about having a SQL install you can maintain and tune, you wouldn't use Azure. Sadly for me, that decision was made before I started working where I work