# sp_Blitz Error on Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sp-blitz

Getting the following error when trying to install sp_Blitz on a Azure SQL Database

> Msg 40515, Level 15, State 1, Procedure sp_Blitz, Line 16 [Batch Start
>   Line 15] Reference to database and/or server name in
>   'master.sys.all_objects' is not supported in this version of SQL
>   Server.

I can't see anything in the [comments on the SP](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/sp_Blitz.sql) to suggest that Azure SQL Database isn't supported

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In the [readme](https://github.com/BrentOzarULTD/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/blob/dev/README.md) of the first responder kit there is a statement on Azure SQL DB**

> Azure SQL DB - It's a dice roll. Microsoft changes DMV contents in
> here without warning, so no guarantees.

There is another explanation by [Scott Hodgin](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/60085/scott-hodgin) and a possible workaround by [Henrik Staun Poulsen](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/28463/henrik-staun-poulsen) in [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228321/install-firstresponderkit-in-azure-sql-db/228345#228345).

**Per Henrik's words**

> I've tried to make a version of sp_blitz that works on Azure SQL DB.
> See [here](https://github.com/HenrikStaunPoulsen/SQL-Server-First-Responder-Kit/tree/issue_1970/HenrikStaunPoulsen)  Now, I'm looking for people that will test it.

You could test his version of sp_blitz and give him some feedback.