# SQL Grease : Strategy to maintain Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, maintenance

I am a developer that dabbles a *few* things across the entire stack. I have never had the opportunity to work to work on a product that uses a monolith Azure SQL database on a Premium tier scaled up to the limits.

There are plans to break the domain into bite sized instances that make sense and can be maintained by smaller teams. However until then there are few challenges that need to dealt with.

- We are currently using **SQLGrease** on a basic plan to understand the challenges.
- Searching for maintaining azure database gives me lot of scripts from unknown people of the internet that will "help" with the situation
- I am interested in learning if there is a strategy people have used in the past that can help me prioritize the challenges and help identify low hanging fruits / big wins compared to efforts

What have I tried ?

- I'm filling this out as I don't want to give the impression that I am NOT putting efforts and simply offloading research that I can do

1. I'm prioritizing queries by CPU time with most execution
2. Identify and maintain indexes
3. Identify and maintain statistics
4. Setting up automated mechanism to update statistics on existing index / objects that may or might not be helping the situation at the moment

I am using [@yochananrachamim/AzureSQL: AzureSqlMaintenance](https://github.com/yochananrachamim/AzureSQL/blob/master/AzureSQLMaintenance.txt) for identifying and maintaining existing index and statistics

Comment: I fail to understand why I am being downvoted for this question, It would helpful if you could just comment before making a downvote decision. Thanks! I understand the question has a broad scope.. however what I need is to discuss pointers to go in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download:

- [First Responder Kit](https://www.brentozar.com/first-aid/), this will tell you what to focus on first
- [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/), for everything that is Backup, Integrity Check, and Index and Statistics Maintenance
- [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/), will help you to understand what is going on
- [Erik Darling](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/#), for further inspection

Recently I'm diving into [MadeiraToolbox](https://github.com/MadeiraData/MadeiraToolbox) repository and there is a lot of interesting material.

I've never used **SQLGrease**, I'm sure you can find a lot of out-of-the-box solutions in that monitoring tool.

People are downvoting your question because is too general. Your question need to have a goal like "*how to do this?*"

Next time you are looking for an alternative for SQLGrease ask a question on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for the direction! I did run into FIrst Responders kit while I was digging at this problem. However I got the impression that it did not support Azure Sql DB at the moment.
You are right. I happened to mentioned SQLGrease just to give a headsup  that we are using some form of third party monitoring. But I wasn't married to figure out a solution that involved just SQLGrease. Thanks again for the pointers!!

Comment: On Azure SQL Databases it might/might-not work: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/228321/install-firstresponderkit-in-azure-sql-db

Comment: Glen Berry makes 2 versions of his performance script: https://glennsqlperformance.com/ one for SQL Server, one for Azure SQL Databases

Answer (score 1):

Some general advice -

You mention a "Azure SQL database on a Premium tier scaled up to the limits". One thing to check is that you have [MAXDOP configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/configure-max-degree-of-parallelism?view=azuresql). The default value of 0 could cause you issues with a larger number of CPU cores available.

I don't have any experience with SQLGrease.  I would recommend enabling query store if it's not already enabled regardless of any other monitoring tools.  Query store can provide a quick-fix solution to parameter sniffing issues and provide data that you can use to troubleshoot other performance issues.  If you have a CPU bottleneck, query store can give you the top queries by total CPU for a given time period.

SQLGrease might be able to add some value on top of query store - it's worth learning to use the monitoring tool you have.  If it doesn't support AzureDB I created an open-source monitoring tool, [DBA Dash](https://dbadash.com) that does a good job or monitoring AzureDB. Ideally, your monitoring tool should at least provide top waits over time.  This can be a good place to start.

Moving from a large DB to multiple small DBs *could* be beneficial but ideally, you need to understand the root cause of your performance issues.  It's possible that a simple fix will dramatically reduce resource utilization.  This might avoid expensive re-architecture or buy you additional time to implement it.  Hiring consultants to help or investing in training might also be worth considering.

It's also worth noting that performance fixes can also come from the app side.  e.g. Reduce the number of queries sent to SQL Server by removing duplicate calls, implementing caching etc.

Hope this helps